# Box design with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

[image: box theorem]

I found this box, but didn't know the design. Can you tell me which library or packages are used to design it.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look at tcolorbox, which is a Bit more streamlined: https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox . Also check out the categories mentioned there. If you want a more scribbled look, you can do that with tikz.

Comment: You should consider accepting answers that were provided, since they are very accurate. This values helpers work and state that your needs have been fulfilled, preventing other members from uselessly working on your questions.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `tcolorbox` package. Here a short example to get you started how to draw these "handdrawn" lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{emerald}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tikzset{decoration={random steps,segment length=2mm,amplitude=0.6pt}}

\newtcbtheorem{mytheo}{Theorem}{
  coltitle=green!80!black,
  colback=lightgray!20,
  colbacktitle=lightgray!20,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\ECFAugie,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.18cm,xshift=-0.5mm},
  boxed title style={
    tikz={rotate=4,transform shape},
    frame code={
      \draw[decorate,fill=lightgray!20] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
    }
  },
  frame code={
    \draw[decorate,fill=lightgray!20,drop shadow] (frame.north east) rectangle (frame.south west);
  },
}{th}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo}{}{theoexample}
content...
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

[image]